# Column value can't be resolved by View

Tags: oracle, sql-view

We have a view called `xx_customer_v` and when I run the below query the record will not return the record even though it saved in the database exactly how I am trying to return it.

Value Stored `Party_Site_Attribute20 = 'Bob.Green@email.com 09-04-2021 10:42:30'`

If I `TRIM(PARTY_SITE_ATTRIBUTE20)` it will return the row

If I `UPPER(PARTY_SITE_ATTRIBUTE20) = UPPER('Bob.Green@email.com 09-04-2021 10:42:30')` It will return meaning it doesn't have trailing spaces

If I `LENGTH(DUMP(PARTY_SITE_ATTRIBUTE20) and LENGTH(DUMP(CAST('Bob.Green@email.com 09-04-2021 10:42:30' AS VARCHAR(150)))` in the select statement they return the same number of characters and type. The package that runs this query `VARCHAR(150)` and table is `VARCHAR(150)`.

Basically if I run them through some type of function it will be able to locate the record but if no function is used then it will not locate the record. Any idea on how I can get it to return? The below query works on other records in the DB but something is up with this one record.

```
SELECT * 
FROM XX_CUSTOMER_V 
WHERE PARTY_SITE_ATTRUBUTE20 = 'Bob.Green@email.com 09-04-2021 10:42:30'
```

-Update- If I query the direct table `hz_party_sites` for `ATTRIBUTE20` it will return with no issue. Issue is only when its in a view.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question with a [MRE] that includes: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for the undelying table(s); the `CREATE VIEW` statement for the `xx_customer_v` view; and the `INSERT` statement for the row(s) that is causing the issue so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18e0678d665ec216c7ead875bff21330)

Comment: What does `dump()` actually show for that value from the table?

Comment: ```Typ=96 Len=39: 66,111,98,46,71,114,101,101,110,64,101,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109,32,48,57,45,48,52,45,50,48,50,49,32,49,48,58,52,50,58,51,48```